# Why I do have strange extra space?

Tags: qt, qwidget

I have a `SingleTweetWidget` to display a tweet.

If I put it into a `QScrollArea`, everything is working fine.

```
class TweetListWidget(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, client=None, parent=None):
        super(TweetListWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi()

    def setupUi(self):
        self.layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

    def setModel(self, model):
        self.model = model
        self.model.rowsInserted.connect(self._rowsInserted)

    def _rowsInserted(self, parent, start, end):
        for index in range(start, end + 1):
            item = self.model.get_item(index)
            widget = SingleTweetWidget(self.client, item)
            self.layout.insertWidget(index, widget)
```

[image: SingleTweetWidget in a QScrollArea]

But, if I put it into a dialog, there will be some extra space.

```
def setupUi(self, widget):
    super(NewpostWindow, self).setupUi(widget)
    tweet = SingleTweetWidget(self.client, self.tweet, self)
    self.verticalLayout.insertWidget(0, tweet)
```

[image: SingleTweetWidget in a QDialog]

Please notice the space between the time (`6s ago`) and the blue separator line.

Where is it come from? I have no idea with it.

By the way, you can get the source code of SingleTweetWidget from https://github.com/WeCase/WeCase/blob/dev-0.06/src/TweetListWidget.py

Comment: Do you mean vertical or horizontal space? I don't really got it from your image. It will be good to mention it ;)

Comment: I mean vertical space. You can see a lot of extra space between the time (`6m ago`) and the blue separator line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`QDialog` has a layout which put a vertical space between widgets. It's because the default minimum height of `QDialog` is higher than the height of the two widgets. You can use `self->setMinimumHeight(int)` and `self->setMaximumHeight(int)` and the width variants or `self->setFixedSize(w,h)`, etc...

You can set max/min width/height with every widget.

Read something about `QLayout`, `QDialog` and the Qt and see some examples. Qt have very good documentation. See

http://qt-project.org/doc/

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/examples-layouts.html

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#setFixedSize

Comment: The trouble is I don't know a suitable `MinimumHeight`/`MaximumHeight` before SingleTweetWidget had been create.

Comment: I tried to set `sizePolicy`, such as `QtGui.QSizePolicy.Preferred`, `QtGui.QSizePolicy.Maximum`, `QtGui.QSizePolicy.Minimum`, or `HeightForWidth(True)`, none of them works.

Comment: You don't have to know `MinimumHeight`/`MaximumHeight` within the future content of text areas. For this purpose there is `QScrollBar` in the text areas and widgets, so the origin widgets won't expand and then the `QDialog` won't expand also. If you know Max/Min in time of creating SingleTweetWidget, use constructor params :)

Comment: I don't want to put a `scrollbar` on a `NewpostWindow`, that makes the retweet less readable. I just want to find a way to make `SingleTweetWidget` shrinks to minimal height. I can do that by resizing the dialog with mouse. If I can do it programmatically, it will be a good workaround.

Comment: Try to set the vertical spacing in `QLayout` (http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/qgridlayout.html#verticalSpacing-prop). More static and ugly solution can be to set the MaximumHeight to the sum of widgets inside, but it is so ugly and you have to update this value when widgets are resized (like new conent is appended)

Comment: And you should set the sizePolicy of the widgets inside of the layout (not the whole GUI, or dialog, window, whatever), if you set them  both to expanding they should take all the space given (of course there are some default minimum spaces which you will want as I believe)

Comment: It is a `QVBoxLayout`, I can not set a vertical spacing.

Comment: Oops? Finally, a simple trick just works for me. `self.verticalLayout.setStretch(0, 1)`.